# Promise chain executing out of order

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

```
Account.findByOwnerID(userID)
.then(function(account) {
    return validateTo(account, userID);
})
.then(User.findByUsername(email))
```

In this case, findByOwnerID runs, but as soon as the Promise.all() inside of it starts running, findByUsername starts being executed, skipping over validateTo.

A simple change in the code makes it all work how I'd expect.

```
Account.findByOwnerID(userID)
.then(function(account) {
    return validateTo(account, userID);
})
.then(function() {
    return User.findByUsername(email);
})
```

Using this code, findByOwnerID runs, then when it resolves, validateTo runs. When that resolves, findByUsername is ran.

So why does this work and not the one above? The way I understood promise chaining was that each .then() expected to be given a promise, which when resolved, will trigger the next .then().

Some background on the functions used (I can give more details in these if needed)

Account.findByOwnerID and User.findByUsername are functions that return a promise. Inside of that promise they use Promise.all.then(function() {resolve()}, to return the main promise and continue the chain.

validateTo is a function that returns a promise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has nothing to do with promises. It's simple function invocation.

You're effectively asking why `a(b())` behaves differently than `a(function () { b() })`. The simple answer is that in the first, `b()` is executed and then the result is passed to `a()`, while in the second, `a()` executes and is passed a function that may or may not be invoked at some point in the future.

`.then(b())` invokes `b` immediately, and the return value (whatever that may be) is passed into `then`. This is what your first case does.

`.then(function () { b() })` passes a function into `then`. It's up to `then` to decide when/if to execute that function. This is what your second case does.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly? A() and B() are both functions that return promises. 

A().then(B()) will start running A, then immediately start running B, before A even resolves. If I run A().then( function() { B() } ), B waits until A has resolved?

Comment: @Elliot Yes. In the former, `A()` will run and return a promise, and then `B()` will be executed and its promise will be passed as the sole argument to `then` on A's promise.

Comment: @Elliot In the later, `A()` runs and returns a promise and then its `then` method is invoked and passed a function. That function doesn't get executed until A's promise has resolved.

Comment: It might be simpler to see why `a(b())` behaves differently than `a(b)`.

Comment: Yes @jib that is a simpler way to think about this. Took me a bit of thinking to understand what meagar was saying, but now it all makes sense.